# iOS black line on navigation controller transition

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

When the push/pop transition is performed on my view controller(which has large title and search bar embedded in navigation item), the black line appears briefly, like this:

[image]

I've basically tried changing all the navigation bar colour related things, but nothing helped.

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: try changing your tableView background color to white and set cell background color as black

Comment: @Shezad this does remove the line, but now the part underneath the tableView content is white but should be black. Have any ideas how to fix that?

Comment: forget about the above solution and try setting the content offset of tableView to zero or height of search bar in viewWillAppear

Comment: @shezad this removes the large line which appears on back press, but the table view is scrolled too much then. The top row is the 4th row overall.

Comment: can you show the code you used to set content offset ?

Comment: @shezad tableView.setContentOffset(CGPoint.zero, animated: true)

Comment: let offset = CGPoint.init(x: 0, y: self.searchBar.bounds.height)
 self.tableView.setContentOffset(offset, animated: false)

Comment: try the above code with your searchbar height

Comment: @shezad same outcome

Comment: so need to see your code, can you share a sample project

Comment: @shezad i uploaded the sample project which outlines my project and the transition issue to github: https://github.com/dCubelic/NavigationSample
(just make sure to scroll down to show search bar first, then try the transitions)

Comment: because of bouncing it shows the background color, so you could use the first solution and set a footer view in the remaining part of tableView with black color

Answer (score 0):

```
extension UINavigationBar {


    var customStyle: NavigationBarCustomStyle {
        set(style) {
            switch style {
            case .clear:
                self.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
            self.shadowImage = UIImage()
            self.tintColor = .white
            self.isTranslucent = false

                break
            case .bottomLine:
                self.tintColor = .gray
                self.backgroundColor = .yellow
                self.isTranslucent = false
                break
            }
        }
        get {
            return self.customStyle
        }
    }
}

enum NavigationBarCustomStyle {
    case clear
    case bottomLine
//  case white
}
```

at ViewController >> viewDidLoad method put below line:

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.customStyle = .clear
```

Comment: Changing isTranslucent property to false breaks status bar and search bar colours so I get this: https://postimg.cc/image/q11em86rv/

Comment: @dCubelic try to remove this line please

Comment: Nothing changed when removing that line. When I remove the setBackgroundImage line, then it reverts to old behaviour.

Comment: still the same :/

Answer (score 0):

Try set navbar's background color to white (depend on your case) fix the problem for me, though there still another glitch but its better :)

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.navigationController?.view.backgroundColor = .white
}
```

Comment: this does not help, unfortunately :/